# CADisplayLink problem animation iphone xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, cadisplaylink

Hi everybody I'm french so scuse me for my bad english.
So my problem is when I use CADisplayLink to animate one image at 60fps, it works fine but when I want to animate two image I have near 40fps.
So what can I do.
please help me .
thank you.

Comment: Remember to flag an answer as the correct solution. If you are not satisfied with the answer, provide more information by editing your question. If you found the answer yourself, post the answer and mark this as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with CADisplayLink. The problem is that rendering takes to much time, and it's not possible to draw faster. You'd better optimize your drawing code (maybe reduce the image size).